# NSDate return hour/day/week

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

Snaps in Instagram program, date shown as (for example) 2 hours ago/3 days ago/ 1 week ago.. I have "2013-03-20 16:02:48".. how can I get string "2 days ago"?

Comment: this question is not xcode related, as it doesnt matter, if the code was written in Xcode, vi or entered by using a telegraph. please us the Xcode tag only in situation, where you want to know something about the xcode editor itself.

Comment: NSDateComponents object, not for iOS? I have resolved this question with this object. So don't get smart

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: so you clearly didnt get what I was saying: Xcode is an editor not more not less. it is used to write programs, but it is not a programming language (thats objective-c). it is not a collection of classes and functions you use with the programming language (that is Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch). it is not an operation system (that is Mac OS X/iOS). Xcode also is not — nor contains — NSDateComponents. this belongs to the framework. You can write iOS programs by using Objective-C, cocoa-touch and NSDateComponents in any other editor. it just dosnt matter. Xcode is irrelevant and you tagging is putting noise

Comment: onto the Xcode tag, meaning post that are corectly tagged xcode get lost. So please get smart — at least smarter. Developers not knowing their tools are a burden.

Comment: and btw: revenge down votes are childish

Comment: from the [xcode-tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info): «This tag should only be used for questions about the Xcode tool, itself, not for programming questions for which you happen be using Xcode.»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) and [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to calculate differences and articulate similar to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

There is a open source project

https://github.com/billgarrison/SORelativeDateTransformer

from its documentation:

> For example, when the current date-time is 2010-12-05 11:30, then
>   ... 2010-12-05 11:00 is transformed to "30 minutes ago"
>   ... 2010-12-01 11:00 is transformed to "5 days ago"
>   ... 2010-12-25 08:00 is transformed to "in 2 weeks"
>
> ```
> // Display a file's creation date relative to today's date
> NSURL *someFilePath = ...;
> NSDictionary *attribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:someFilePath error:NULL];
>
> NSDate *dateModified = [attribs fileModificationDate];
>
> // fileModificationDate is 2010-10-01 12:00:00TZ; 
> // Date now is 2010-10-30 12:00:00TZ
>
> SORelativeDateTransformer *relativeDateTransformer = [[SORelativeDateTransformer alloc] init];
> NSString *relativeDate = [relativeDateTransformer transformedValue: dateModified];
>
> NSLog (@"This file was modified %@.", relativeDate); // ==> "This file was modified 3 weeks ago."
> ```

Comment: Good one. Note however that its license requires attribution.

Comment: not, if you just look up some implementation details. anyway: give credit where credit is due…

Comment: I'm not minding attribution. On the contrary, my comment was meant as a reminder to respect the license because attribution is one of the requirements which are most easy to "forget".

Comment: ah, ok. I would happily add attribution in Helvetica Neue all caps 24.0 just for the localization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a library somewhere which will do that for you.

But it's not to hard anyway. It is possible to break a NSDate down into its components. It is then easy to compare them and to write some if then else code to cover all the wanted cases.

Here's one example from one of my projects where I am resolving a Date to the appropriate weekday within the last seven days:

```
NSString *resultDateString;

// First, reduce the two dates we want to compare to the scope of days by erasing hours, minutes and seconds

unsigned int flagA = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *compsA = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flagA fromDate:myObjectsDate];
[compsA setHour:0];
[compsA setMinute:0];
[compsA setSecond:0];
NSDate *checkDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:compsA];

unsigned int flagB = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *partsB = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flagB fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[compsB setHour:0];
[compsB setMinute:0];
[compsB setSecond:0];
NSDate *nowDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:compsB];

// Get the interval between the two dates, interval is still in seconds, but since it is calculated using days only, it will be precisely 0 if the day is the same    

NSTimeInterval interval = [searchDate timeIntervalSinceDate:nowDate];

// check if the objects date is today. If it isn't, find out which day it is and name it appropriately

if (interval == 0) {

    resultDateString = [NSString stringWithString:@"Today"];

} else {

   unsigned int flagC = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
   NSDateComponents *compsC = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flagC fromDate:myObjectsDate];

   switch ([compsC weekday]) {
       case 1:
           resultDateString = @"Sunday";
           break;
       case 2:
           resultDateString = @"Monday";
           break;
       case 3:
           resultDateString = @"Tuesday";
           break;
       case 4:
           resultDateString = @"Wednesday";
           break;
       case 5:
           resultDateString = @"Thursday";
           break;
       case 6:
           resultDateString = @"Friday";
           break;
       case 7:
           resultDateString = @"Saturday";
           break;

       default:
           break;
   }

}
```

This is only an excerpt, note that this code snippet doesn't check if the interval is longer than 7 days for example, because I covered such cases differently in my code. But I think it will give you a basic idea of how to do this.